# Permanent mouse hover effect on buttons

Tags: hover, mousehover, permanent

I made a site with lots of ghostbuttons that change color when the user hovers his or her mouse over them. The buttons are arranged by color like a rainbow and I want them to stay active/colored even when the mouse stops hovering over it so that when the user hovers over the all the buttons, all the buttons will be colored at the same time.

The buttons are all placed within bootstrap columns.

I have no experience with JavaScript so pure CSS would be ideal for me. But if JavaScript is the best way to go with this please let me know exactly how to implant it in HTML and CSS.

Please don't mind any mistakes in the spelling, I'm dutch and dyslectic :P

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean to ask when user once hover an element it remains active, leaving like a trail behind ?

Comment: Yes exactly! So that once all the buttons have been hovered over there all still colored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this at the bottom of your code just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script>
   $(".btn").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","pink");               
    });
</script>
```

You can change the (".btn") bit to any class on the page, so if you only wanted it to change btn-primary classes you'd have (".btn-primary") etc.

Comment: Thanks it works! but how am I supposed to give all the buttons the right property's? like I need them to be transparent with a colored border and colored text in them. is this the way to do that? And can I use HEX colors in your code?

   $(".btn-blue").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","none" "border-color","blue" "color", "blue");               
    });

Comment: This is the default bootstrap button CSS:

.btn-default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}

You could create one called btn-red1 (in your own css file) and change the properties so it was one shade of red, then create another class called btn-red2 with a lighter/darker shade, and keep doing that until you've got the rainbow.

Comment: Yes I know, I didn't use that button but I understand and it worked with my button. The colored border is also working now. The only thing I can't do is set a second property. How can I set both the border color and the text color? 

<script>
   $(".ghost-button-semi-transparent-pink").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css("border-color","#FF0040")("color","#FF0040");
    });
</script>

Like I said the border is working like this but the text is still white. Do you know what my mistake is?

Comment: Instead of a new set of brackets you just keep adding things on separating them with commas, so you'd use:

 $(".ghost-button-semi-transparent-pink").mouseout(function() { $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0040", "color", "#FF0040"); });

Comment: Many thanks for the reply's! But the text color still isn't staying pink. when I stop hovering the border stays colored but the text goes back to white.

Comment: Somehow only the first property I use stays when I stop hovering. If I put the text first it works but the border goes back to white.

Comment: My apologies, I messed up the colons somewhere. Try this: $(".ghost-button-semi-transparent-pink").mouseout(function() { 
  $(this).css({
  "border-color": "#FF0040", 
  "color"     : "#FF0040"
 });
});

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Could you mark this as 'answered' so it can help others? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again and make things more complicated, but I was wondering if it is possible to make one of the buttons a reset button so all the colored buttons go back to white without the page refreshing.

Comment: Inside the <script> tags underneath the other button function, you could put something like:

$(".reset-btn").click(function() { $(".color-btn").css({ "border-color": "white", "color" : "black" }); });

Make a button with the class .reset-btn and the above code will reset every button with the .color-btn class. Alternatively, if all your buttons already share a class, you could use that one instead (if they're bootstrap buttons they'll already have a .btn class)

Comment: Thank you! All the colored buttons have a different id like: .ghost-button-semi-transparent-red or .ghost-button-semi-transparent-blue. So I should probably add another class named .ghost-button